# Getting compilation errors when compiling assembly in separate file

Tags: c++, assembly

This is my (very simple) program. It works perfectly when the function `function` is inside my own .cpp file but when I link it to another `.asm` file I then get errors. I'm compiling in Visual C++ 2010 Express and I believe this is 32-bit assembly I'm using.

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int function();

int main() {

    std::cout << function();

    std::cin.get();
}
```

`function` is defined as:

```
.code

function proc
    mov eax, 50

    ret
function endp

end
```

And I'm getting the errors:

```
error A2013: .MODEL must precede this directive
error A2034: must be in segment block : function
error A2034: must be in segment block
error A2034: must be in segment block
fatal error A1010: unmatched block nesting : function
```

This is my first time using Assembly so I'm not familiar with these errors. What do they mean and how do I get this program to work?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a .model and a cpu declaration, and usually a stack declaration as well.
Take a look here:
http://www.talreg.com/?cat=58

Comment: I did what the first video said. I'm now getting the error: `unresolved external symbol _function referenced in function _main`. Also: `fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`

Comment: @David: Maybe a stupid advice, but have you tried naming your function `_function` in the asm? It looks like the linker is looking for `_function` instead of `function`, might be a naming convention

Comment: @AndyProwl Nope, [same dumb error](http://gyazo.com/d35fe81e589e99e3fde562da9243e361).

Comment: @David: That's not what I meant: I meant putting a trailing underscore in the asm, not in the .cpp. It looks like this naming convention is adopted to use a trailing underscore, and your screenshot seems to confirm it (see that now the unresolved symbol is for `__function`, with 2 underscores)?

Comment: @David: In other words, keep the `.cpp` file as you had it in the original question, and change the `.asm` file to have `_function proc` instead of `function proc` and `_function endp` instead of `function endp`

Comment: @AndyProwl [This is the c++](http://gyazo.com/7df0dfa3d7772ea42b72ec2256435132) and [this is the assembly](http://gyazo.com/c93dd9b09df8bf83cdd958c743e43490)

Comment: @David: If the error is still the same, then I guess I have no more suggestions :-(

Comment: @AndyProwl I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the linker or my compiler settings. I just downloaded this compiler. Thanks for the help anyway. I'll get it eventually.